# Colspan not working on bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nested bootstrap `table` and I want `colspan` to work on it, but it does not seem to work.

At the end of the day, I would like to end up with something like this:

```
   ____________________
  |   Col1 | Col2      |
  |--------------------|
  |This is data I want |
  |--------------------|
  | Col 1  | Col 2     |
  ----------------------
```

I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/pJkXd/2/) to demonstrate the full functionality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have fixed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/pJkXd/2/)

```
 <tr class="child">
     <td colspan="7">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="7">Expand This To Full Table</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I checked the fiddle and found it is not functioning.

Answer (score 5):

As G-Man mentioned, you need to have the outermost `td` to do the `colspan`. The inner table actually does not need any `colspan` as follows. Although, I don't think it would be a good idea to nest `table` within a `table`, but it's really up to you depending on the situation. [Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/pJkXd/3/)

```
<td colspan="7">Some Content Here</td>
```